# Video Object in mxml for different resolutions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mxml

I have developed a VideoChat application using Flash Builder from Cirrus in a serverless Mode.

I have aligned video Objects using `video.x` and `video.y`.
When the application runs on a high or lower resolution system it deforms.

Please suggest me how to align the video objects...

Answer (score 0):

Layouts or HGroup/HBox, VGroup/VBox concept will useful to you for align Video Objects in horizontal/vertical.